# Laravel Mix hot reloading inside the package

Tags: php, laravel, package, webpack-hmr

I've been trying to create an admin panel for Laravel (I know, there is a Laravel Nova now for 99$ for a single site) and all I've been doing is trying to build all of this functionality on top of **laravel/laravel** package.

What I've seen with Nova, is that it is a separate package, which is seamlessly integrates with Laravel by simply dragging and dropping the folder with Nova to the root directory of the Laravel application.

Even though, I have an idea (and a little bit of experience) on how to replicate (and maybe even enhance Nova functionality), I've no idea on how to make HMR working with the package.

Let's say my package name is Niva (just an example), with the folder named **niva** placed inside the Laravel folder. The ***webpack.mix.js*** is the same as in the **Laravel Horizon** package.

So far, I've no problems with accessing routes defined in the package, I'm able to load views from the package by accessing specified route, even authentication works just fine. However, I have to manually compile the package first, then publish the assets, and only then I can view the changes I've made to the source code.

**Example package base routes:**

- **Web:** _http://localhost/niva (Only need for HMR to be present here)
- **Api:** _http://localhost/api/niva

**Example package base directories and files:**

- **Root:** /var/www/localhost/niva
- **Public:** /var/www/localhost/niva/public
- **Resources:** /var/www/localhost/niva/resources
- **Webpack:** /var/www/localhost/niva/webpack.mix.js

**What I'm asking about is:** is it possible to enable HMR for the package, and how it should be done?

**P.S.** I've been thinking of symlinking the public directory from the package to the public **vendor/niva** folder, but still no result (I'm pretty sure I'm missing something here).